# How to show Monte Carlo methods converge to an estimate which minimizes mean squared error?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, proofs, monte-carlo-methods, convergence

In chapter six of Sutton and Barto (p.128), they claim Monte Carlo methods converge to an estimate minimizing the mean squared error. How can this be shown formally?

Bump